# How to Ensure Installation of Mobile Web App on Device Only?

Tags: angularjs, mobile-website

I'm working on an AngularJS mobile web app and am getting ready to deploy to Firebase Hosting. Does anyone know how to ensure that only devices can install the web app and prevent desktop browsers from viewing? I'm trying to protect the client's intellectual property as well as my own by making a reasonable attempt to disallow the source code from being read. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to prevent the reverse engineering of any web application.

Developing a mobile application using native code may make you feel more secure about the intellectual property, however once a would be attacker gets the software on to their own hardware they will have the opportunity to defeat your software.

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for an approach where one message will be presented to the user if it's a desktop and the install process if it's a mobile device. I've seen it somewhere before a few years ago but have been unable to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using ng-device-detector to determine whether the user was using a mobile device or not, and delivering a different template page depending. This library contains an isMobile() function that works great.